# List reverse is not working for my pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, reverse

I need to make a patter like this:

```
---------.|.---------
------.|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
-------WELCOME-------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|.------
---------.|.---------
```

The problem is that i can't reverse the second part which is the same as the first part just reversed.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(n // 2):
   pattern = [('.|.' * (2 * i + 1)).center(m, '-')]
   print('\n'.join(pattern))

print('WELCOME'.center(m, '-'))

for i in range(n // 2):
   pattern = [('.|.' * (2 * i + 1)).center(m, '-')]
   print('\n'.join(pattern[::-1]))
```

The `pattern[::-1]` should be the reversed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> List reverse is not working for my pattern?

your `pattern` list has only one element so the reverse of the list will be the same list

---

to print the second part of your output in the mirror you have to print from the last line (as was in the first part) to the first line:

```
n = 10
m = 10
base_str = '.|.'
for i in range(n // 2):
    pattern = (base_str * (2 * i + 1)).center(m * len(base_str), '-')
    print(pattern)

print('WELCOME'.center(m * len(base_str), '-'))

for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
    pattern = (base_str * (2 * i + 1)).center(m * len(base_str), '-')
    print(pattern)
```

**output:**

```
-------------.|.--------------
----------.|..|..|.-----------
-------.|..|..|..|..|.--------
----.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.-----
-.|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|.--
-----------WELCOME------------
-.|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|.--
----.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.-----
-------.|..|..|..|..|.--------
----------.|..|..|.-----------
-------------.|.--------------
```